# Spring+ Hibernate :How to map single session factory in multiple modules (deployed as jar)

Tags: spring, hibernate, struts2

I am working on Spring + Struts2 and Hibernate currently, My requirement is :

1. I have Master module which will make DB connection, shared by all other modules (deployed as Jar) in the system.
2. All Module specific .hbm and persistence classes will exists in Module itself
   So for example My master module will have Hibernate connection file (through spring) will all .hbm mapping files, Below is the sample of Hibernate connection made through Spring.

   ```
   <bean id="dataSourceErik" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
     <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
     <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true" />
     <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="120000" />
     <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="30000" />
   </bean>
   <bean id="sessionFactoryErik"
   class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
     <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceErik" />
     <property name="hibernateProperties">
       <value>
           hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
           hibernate.generate_statistics=true
           hibernate.show_sql=false
           hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=10
           hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer=true
       hibernate.cache.provider_class=org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider                hibernate.cache.region.factory_class=org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory
           hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=true
           hibernate.cache.use_query_cache=true
           net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName=configuration/ehcache.xml
       </value>
     </property>

     <property name="mappingLocations">
       <list>
           <value>classpath:configuration/hibernate/Abc.hbm.xml</value>
           <value>classpath:configuration/hibernate/Xyz.hbm.xml</value>
      </list>
     </property>        
   </bean>
   <bean id="AbcActionDAO" class="au.com.master.persistance.dao.AbcDbSession">
       <constructor-arg ref="sessionFactoryErik" />
   </bean>
   <bean id="XyzActionTypeDAO"class="au.com.master.persistance.dao.XyzDbSession">
       <constructor-arg ref="sessionFactoryErik" />
   </bean>
   ```

if i add below code in above xml i can access '''sessionFactory''' and can connect with the DB. as i am giving the path of deployed subModule jar file, see below code :

```
<property name="mappingJarLocations">
<list>
   <value>WEB-INF/lib/subModule.jar</value>
</list>
</property>
```

All above .hbm and DAO/DbSession classes exists in Master module. Now i want to use this '''sessionFactoryErik''' in my Sub modules deployed as jar. so for that i created another xml file in Sub module which will take reference of above '''sessionFactoryErik''' and will have mappings of this module specific .hbm and DAO/DbSession. Refer below code:

```
 <bean id="sessionFactoryMonitor" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
     <property name="sessionFactoryErik" ref="sessionFactoryErik" />
     <property name="mappingLocations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:configuration/hibernate/DDDType.hbm.xml</value>
        </list>
      </property>        
 </bean>

 <bean id="testActionDAO" class="au.com.java.subModule.persistance.dao.DddActionDbSession">
    <constructor-arg ref="sessionFactoryMonitor" />
</bean>
```

if i deployed the project and reboot the server i am getting below error.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactoryMonitor' defined in URL [jar:file:/home/developer/Project/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/webapps/erik/WEB-INF/lib/erik-monitor-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/configuration/spring-monitor-dao.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'sessionFactoryErik' of bean class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean]: Bean property 'sessionFactoryErik' is not writable or has an invalid setter method.
```

Can anyone help me for this. How can i get the same session object in sub module as only Master module can make connection as it will not have any knowledge of its deployed (deployed as jar) module.

Thanks.
Tapan

Comment: the class org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean doesn't have a property called sessionFactoryErik.

Answer (score 1):

the class `org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean` doesn't have a property called sessionFactoryErik. I am guessing that you are injecting your datasource to LocalSessionFactoryBean. if so Change this

```
<bean id="sessionFactoryMonitor" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
     <property name="sessionFactoryErik" ref="sessionFactoryErik" />
     <property name="mappingLocations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:configuration/hibernate/DDDType.hbm.xml</value>
        </list>
      </property>        
 </bean>
```

to this

```
 <bean id="sessionFactoryMonitor" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
     <property name="dataSource" ref="sessionFactoryErik" />
     <property name="mappingLocations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:configuration/hibernate/DDDType.hbm.xml</value>
        </list>
      </property>        
 </bean>
```

Comment: Hi KyelJmD,I have added what happened when i tried your suggestion in below answer, Please have a look and suggest. Thanks.

Comment: Hi KyelJmd,I tried your solution but it didn't work. i got below error :
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl] to required type [javax.sql.DataSource] for property 'dataSource': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
at....
Then changed property ref from sessionFactoryErik to dataSourceErik defined as in Master File,it didn't give any error at bootup but when i run the application and tried to hit DB, it give me below error:
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread at...

Answer (score 0):

sessionFactoryErik bean returns **org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl** object,

so you should specify  **org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl** or its super class

(**SessionFactory**) type in au.com.master.persistance.dao.XyzDbSession constructor

reference.